# Using a while loop to check in a for loop if an array includes a string from another source

Tags: javascript

Trying to program a flags trivia game. A flag image appears, along with 3 different answers (with only one answer being the correct flag).

I am using the getFlag() function which creates image elements for each gCountries flag, as well as an array (gFlagsProperties) containing an object for each flag which each contains:

- A unique id
- The src of the image
- 2 random other flag options and the actual flag option (3 overall options for the user to pick one in the game)
- A string of the flag name

I'm trying to use the function render() to ensure that the proper flag image appears on the page - meaning one which one of the options key of the flag object in the gFlagsProperties contains. The while loop infinitely loops and I don't know why.

```
var gFlagsProperties = [];
var gCountries = ['albania', 'chad', 'colombia', 'cyprus', 'denmark', 'gabon', 'hungary', 'iceland', 'latvia', 'madagascar', 'romania', 'serbia'];
var gElFlagsDiv;

function init() {
    render();
}

function getFlag() {
    var options = generateOptions();
    gElFlagsDiv = document.querySelector('.flags');

    for (var i = 1; i <= gCountries.length; i++) {
        var flagImg = document.createElement('img');
        flagImg.src = 'img/' + i + '-' + gCountries[i - 1] + '.gif';
        flagImg.setAttribute('class', 'flag');
        gElFlagsDiv.appendChild(flagImg);

        var flagImgSrc = flagImg.attributes.src.nodeValue;
        var flagImgSrcDash = flagImgSrc.indexOf('-');
        var flagStr = flagImgSrc.slice(flagImgSrcDash + 1, flagImgSrc.length - 4);
        while (!options.includes(flagStr)) {
            options = generateOptions();
            continue;
        }

        gFlagsProperties.push({id: i, image: flagImg, opts: options, correctOpt: flagStr});
    return gFlagsProperties;
}

function render() {
    getFlag();

    var gElOptions = document.querySelector('.options');
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var elOptionBtn = document.createElement('button');
        elOptionBtn.innerText = gFlagsProperties[i].opts[i];

        gFlagsProperties[i].image.style.display = 'block';
        gElOptions.appendChild(elOptionBtn);
        elOptionBtn.setAttribute('class', `option-${i}`);

        var flagImgSrc = gFlagsProperties[i].image.attributes.src.nodeValue;
        var flagImgSrcDash = flagImgSrc.indexOf('-');
        var flagStr = flagImgSrc.slice(flagImgSrcDash + 1, flagImgSrc.length - 4);
    }
        while (!gFlagsProperties[i].opts.includes(flagStr)) {
            init();
        }
}

function generateOptions() {
    var tempRandomizedOptions = gCountries.join();
    var randomizedOptions = tempRandomizedOptions.split(',');
    shuffle(randomizedOptions);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        randomizedOptions.splice(0, randomizedOptions.length - 3);
    }
    return randomizedOptions;
}
```

```
<div class="flags">
            
</div>

<div class="options">
            
</div>
```

Been lost in this for hours. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: If the `while` condition is true `init` is called which calls `render` which presumably looks at the same data, so the `while` condition will be true again, so `init` will be called and that will call `render` etc...

Comment: Hi @Andy , how can I prevent this if I want to make sure the flag image is the same as one of the answers options?

Answer (score 2):

So, I got a little carried away with this.

So, the key thing about your code is that both of your while loops weren't working properly so in this example I've tried to simplify things a little bit.

1. I've restructured the code a little because I didn't have access to your flag images so I used [a flag API](https://flagpedia.net/download/api) instead. This meant that I had to convert your array of countries into an array of objects with `name` and `code` properties. A `forEach` then iterates over the array and gets the flag src information from the API and adds it to the object.
2. I refer to questions made up of flag data rather than flags, as that made it easier for me to understand.
3. All the actual rendering is now done in the `renderQuestion` function. What was `getFlag` and is now called `getQuestionData` only returns data for the main flag, and its options.
4. I added a `checkAnswer` function to ensure the code actually worked properly.

```js
// Cache the elements
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const flags = document.querySelector('.flags');
const options = document.querySelector('.options');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

// Add a listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer, false);

// The new array of country objects
const countries = [{ name: 'albania', code: 'AL' }, { name: 'chad', code: 'TD'}, { name: 'colombia', code: 'CO' }, { name: 'cyprus', code: 'CY' }, { name: 'denmark', code: 'DK' }, { name: 'gabon', code: 'GA' }, { name: 'hungary', code: 'HU' }, { name: 'iceland', code: 'IS' }, { name: 'latvia', code: 'LV' }, { name: 'madagascar', code: 'MG' }, { name: 'romania', code: 'RO' }, { name: 'serbia', code: 'RS' }];

// Iterate over the countries array, and for
// each country add the API link for the flag
// as the country image source
countries.forEach(country => {
  country.src = `https://flagcdn.com/24x18/${country.code.toLowerCase()}.png`;
});

// Grab a random flag from the array
function randomFlag() {
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((countries.length - 1) - 0) + 0);
  return countries[rnd];
}

function getQuestionData() {

  // Make a copy of the flag so we don't
  // overwrite the data in the countries array
  const flag = {...randomFlag()};

  // Create the options array, and add the
  // main flag to it
  flag.options = [];
  flag.options.push(flag)

  // We obviously don't want to add the main
  // flag to the options again so we use while
  // to create a random flag. If its code doesn't
  // match the main flag code add it to options
  // otherwise loop again until there are three flags
  // in the array
  while (flag.options.length < 3) {
    const option = randomFlag();
    if (option.code !== flag.code) {
      flag.options.push(option);
    }
  }

  return flag;

}

function renderQuestion(question) {
  
  // Add the main flag to the flags element
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = question.src;
  img.className = 'flag';
  flags.appendChild(img);

  // Create some HTML by mapping over the question
  // options and using a template string to add the
  // relevant option data to it
  const html = question.options.map(option => {
    return `
      <span class="name">${option.name}</span>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="option"
        value=${option.code}
      />`;
  });
  
  // Add the HTML to the options element
  options.innerHTML = html.join('<br />');

}

function checkAnswer() {

  // Get the checked input from the options element
  const input = options.querySelector('input:checked');

  // Add a message to the result element depending
  // on whether the image value matches the main flag code
  // in the question
  if (input.value === question.code) {
    result.textContent = 'Correct!';
  } else {
    result.textContent = 'Incorrect';
  }
}

// Call `renderQuestion` with a new question.
const question = getQuestionData();
renderQuestion(question);
```

```css
.result, .options, button {  margin-top: 1em; }
.name { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flags"></div>
  <div class="options"></div>
  <button>Check answer</button>
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is *i* being incremented? in

```
while (!gFlagsProperties[i].opts.includes(flagStr)) {
    init();
}
```

And also, init directly calls render, which calls init, so even if you do break out of the while loop somehow, you're going to end up right back where you were.

I think you meant for that while loop to be inside the for, but that's not going to solve the infinite call loop from init -> render -> init